# Who is the gas payer while using transferFrom?

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, gas, transferfrom

In my project, I craeted separate Ethereum accounts for each customer on my Geth server (I have not access to private key in this way normally). Now, customer needs to send out ERC-20 token, whereas he has not any deposited ETH for gas.
After some researches, I found out one way is to use `approve()` and `transferFrom()` as I can provide the enough ETH as gas for transactions. But there are two questions here:

1. Using these methods, who will be the final gas payer? Customer itself, or me as the exchange?
2. When I transfer token on behalf of customer, I have to move the token to my own account. Does it need a new transaction and a new gas?

Comment: Your customer will need gas also for `approve`

Answer (score 1):

> Using these methods, who will be the final gas payer - the customer itself, or me as the exchange?

Your customer will pay gas for executing `approve`.

You will pay gas for executing `transferFrom`.

> When I transfer token on behalf of customer, I have to move the token to my own account.

You don't have to move the token to your own account, that's the whole idea about `transferFrom`:

You move the tokens from the customer's account directly to the destination account.